# Summing $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-2)^k + 1}{3^k}$

Tags: infinite-product

I’m trying to calculate the sum of this by breaking it down into two geometric series:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k2^k + 1}{(3^k)} =\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k} +\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left({\frac13}\right)^{k}$$

But I couldn’t proceed further and would like to get some help! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My Solution:**

\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k2^k+1}{3^k}\\
=&\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-\frac{2}{3})^k\right]+\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{3})^k\right]\\
=&\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{2}{3})}+\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}}\\
=&\frac{21}{10}.
\end{align}

---

**Update:** (starting from $k=1$)

\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k2^k+1}{3^k}\\
=&\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{2}{3})^k\right]+\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{3})^k\right]\\
=&\frac{-\frac{2}{3}}{1-(-\frac{2}{3})}+\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}\\
=&\frac{1}{10}.
\end{align}

Comment: thanks, but im pretty sure that the solution should be: 0.1

Comment: No, the solution is $\frac{21}{10}.$

Comment: ive noticed just now that i set k=0 instead of k=1, sorry for that! but i succed to solve it thanks to your solution!